# Can anybody help with the integral: $\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$ please?

Tags: calculus

I have searched online. I have got a solution from Wolfram but I don't understand it, or how to reach it. If anyone has a method that would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: Any own thoughts about the problem?

Comment: Not really: it looks like a hyperbolic substitution, based on either the numerator or denominator individually, but it's not simplifying. I'm hoping somebody has a suggestion as to the correct substitution.

Comment: Looks like an elliptic integral.

Comment: I guess trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

This is an elliptic integral, but it is interesting to point out what is the explicit value of the integral over $(0,1)$.

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x(1+x)}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{(1-x)(2-x)}}\,dx$$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(2-x^2)}}\,dx =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta$$
or

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}}-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta=\sqrt{2}\left[K\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-E\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\right]$$
by representing the complete elliptic integrals according to Mathematica's notation, such that the argument is the elliptic modulus. A series representation for the RHS is given by
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]^2\frac{2n}{1-2n}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}$$
which due to $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ for large values of $n$, can be approximated by
$$ \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{n}{2^n(2n-1)}=\frac{\pi-4}{4\sqrt{2}}+\log(1+\sqrt{2}).$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality provides a simpler (and tighter) upper bound, namely
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,dx<\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)\,dx\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{6}}.$$
On the other hand both $K\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and $E\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ can be computed through the $\text{AGM}$ and are explicitly related to the $\Gamma$ function. Indeed the former is given by a multiple of $B\left(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{4}\right)$ and the latter is related to the former via Legendre's relation. This gives
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,dx = \color{blue}{\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{2})}-\frac{\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{2})}{2}}$$
which can be proved through Fourier-Legendre expansions, too.

Comment: This is extremely hard to follow. For example, right in the first equation, I see you did $u=x^2$ and $du = 2x dx $ and then put $u=x$ but then I dont follow the second equality. Why is it true

Comment: @JimmySabater: $x\mapsto 1-x$.

Comment: ahh!  I see now. ITs very nice

Answer (score 3):

If the integral is a definite integral with the interval of integration being from $0$ to $1$, here is an approach that makes use of the following form for the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $\operatorname{B} (x,y)$:
$$\operatorname{B} (x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x - 1} (1 - t)^{y - 1} \, dt, \qquad x,y > 0. \tag1$$

Let
$$I = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2}} \, dx.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ yields
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}} \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
Rearranging the integrand we have
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1 - x}{1 - x}} \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{1 - x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - x^2} \sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx. \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (*)
\end{align}

Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ in each of the above two integrals leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 x^{-3/4} (1 - x)^{-1/2} \, dx - \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 x^{-1/4} (1 - x)^{-1/2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 x^{1/4 - 1} (1 - x)^{1/2 - 1} \, dx - \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 x^{3/4 - 1} (1 - x)^{1/2 - 1} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{B} \left (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right ) - \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{B} \left (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right ) \tag2\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left [\frac{\Gamma (\frac{1}{4}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma (\frac{3}{4})} - \frac{\Gamma (\frac{3}{4}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma (\frac{1}{4})} \right ] \tag3\\
&= \frac{\Gamma^2 (\frac{1}{4})}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi}} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{2 \pi}}{\Gamma^2 (\frac{1}{4})}.\tag4
\end{align}

**Explanation**

(2) Each integral is of the form of the Beta function given in (1).

(3) Using the result $\operatorname{B}(x,y) = \dfrac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x + y)}$.

(3) Using $\Gamma (\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma (\frac{3}{4}) = \dfrac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{\Gamma (\frac{1}{4})}$, a result that comes immediately from Euler's reflexion formula for the Gamma function.

---

If it is the indefinite integral you are really after, then as suggested in the comments, your integral can be expressed in terms of *elliptic functions* of the first and second kinds.

From ($*$), namely
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2} \sqrt{u}} - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, du,$$
where $u = x^2$, substituting $u = \sin \theta$ into each of the above integrals one arrives at
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{\operatorname{cosec} x} \, d\theta - \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{\sin \theta} \, d\theta\\
&= - F \left (\frac{\pi - 2 \theta}{4} \Big{|} 2 \right ) + E \left (\frac{\pi - 2 \theta}{4} \Big{|} 2 \right ) + C\\
&= E \left (\frac{\pi - 2 \sin^{-1} (x^2)}{4} \Big{|} 2 \right ) - F \left (\frac{\pi - 2 \sin^{-1} (x^2)}{4} \Big{|} 2 \right ) + C, \qquad -1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1.
\end{align}
Here $F( \phi | k^2)$ is an *elliptic integral* of the first kind while $E(\phi | k^2)$ is an *elliptic integral* of the second kind.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\, dx$$ Let $x=\sinh(t)$ which makes
$$I=\int \sqrt{1-\sinh ^2(t)}\,dt$$ Now, use the fact that $\sin(iz)=i\sinh(z)$; in other words, make $t=i u$ to make
$$I=i \int  \sqrt{1+\sin ^2(u)}\,du$$ Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

**Edit**

May be, as I wrote in a comment, you could consider a series expansion of the integrand
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, x^{2n}$$ in which yhe $a_n$ are defined by
$$a_{n+4}=-\frac{2a_{n+2}-n\,a_n}{n} \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=1,\,\,a_1=0,\,\,a_2=-1,\,\,a_3=0$$ making all odd coeffcients equal to $0$. Starting for $n=0$, the sequence for even values of $n$ is
$$\left\{1,-1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},-\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{16},-\frac{5
   }{16},\frac{35}{128},-\frac{35}{128},\frac{63}{256},-\frac{63}{256},\frac{231}{1
   024},-\frac{231}{1024},\frac{429}{2048},-\frac{429}{2048}\right\}$$

Now, integrate termwise to get, as a truncated series,
$$I=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{10}-\frac{x^7}{14}+\frac{x^9}{24}-\frac{3
   x^{11}}{88}+\frac{5 x^{13}}{208}-\frac{x^{15}}{48}+\frac{35
   x^{17}}{2176}-\frac{35 x^{19}}{2432}+\frac{3 x^{21}}{256}+O\left(x^{23}\right)$$

Comment: Actually, $\sin iz=i\sinh z$.

Comment: @J.G.. Thanks for pointing the typo !

Comment: Thank you. The wiki page is not making that much sense to me, but I will try working through and see where I get to....

Comment: @AMath. Elliptic integrals are a huge domain; don't worry : you will learn about them. For the time, may I suggest you use series expansion of the integrand and integrate termwise. At least, you could see what is the resulting function.